# Is there a way to get a list of endpoints on the anypoint platform

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm looking to get a list of endpoints that are exposed through the anypoint platform either through the CLI or the anypoint REST API.  Even if it is a list of endpoints by the application I could compile them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of endpoints basically by looping through the flows. For my case, I only had endpoints which accept POST and GET requests, so my example is based on that:

```
Collection<FlowConstruct> flowConstructs = muleEventContext.getMuleContext()
                                                           .getRegistry()
                                                           .lookupFlowConstructs(); 
Iterator<FlowConstruct> iterator = flowConstructs.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String flowName = iterator.next().getName();
    if (flowName.startsWith("post:") || flowName.startsWith("get:")) {
        Flow flow = muleEventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().get(flowName);
        // You can process the flowName to extract endpoint
    }
}
```